# What is PHP Fatal error: Invalid opcode 137/4/8.?

Tags: php

### PHP Fatal error:

> Invalid opcode 137/4/8. in xxxxx/Modules/TicketModule.php on line 1349

in the following **code**.

```
do {
    if ($winStatusBreak)
    {
        break;
    }
    if ($ticket['status'] <= StatusConst::$TICKET_SUCCESS)
    {
        $updateData['win_status'] = StatusConst::$ORDER_WAITING_WIN;
        $winStatusBreak = true;
        break;
    }
    if ($ticket['status'] != StatusConst::$TICKET_WINNNG)
    {
        $updateData['win_status'] = StatusConst::$ORDER_WINNED;
        $winStatusBreak = true;    // line 1349
        break;
    } else {
        $updateData['win_status'] = StatusConst::$ORDER_LOSE;
    }

} while (false);
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting your web server?

Comment: Don't know what caused this error.  It's been restarted

Comment: what is in `TicketModule.php on line 1349`

Comment: @Regolith It's marked by a comment in the code.

Comment: are you using any accelerator ? check if its compatible with you current php version